# find out connected any peripheral devices in a system using java?

Tags: java, camera, webcam, usb-drive, image-scanner

How to find out connected any peripheral devices i.e., scanner,webcam,handcam,usb datacard etc in system using java?.These devices list can be shown in applet?.Please help me.

**Update:-**

```
If any wrong on this question,Please write your comments.I corrected this question.
```